# Changing the location Firefox loads the user profile from to custom location

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

On **Windows XP**, how do I get **FireFox 12** to move the load path for the user profile from:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[insert-username]\Application Data\Mozilla
```

to a custom path?

While if needed, I will create a new user to do this, long-term it would be much easier to do a fresh install of FireFox, edit the location profiles are loaded from, and dump an existing backup of a user profile in that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this tutorial](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder), it's a bit outdated but it works.

Comment: +1 @HackToHell: Thanks, appears the tutorial you're linking to is saying that you just (1) Starting the Profile Manager (2) [Create a new](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles#w_creating-a-profile), and change the directory path for that file to the new path need (3) Replace the newly created user profile at the path needed, with the backup-profile. Is that correct, or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @blunders correct !